# qmake system and unescaped backslashes

Tags: qt, mercurial

In my Qt project I have such line:

```
CHANGESET=$$system(hg parents --template '{node\\|short}')
```

Under Linux project is building successfully, but under Windows I'm getting message:

```
'short}' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

As I guess, pipe symbol must be correctly escaped. Can anybody explain this case?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question has to do with Windows `cmd.exe`, not so much with mercurial proper. So, read up on `cmd` shell syntax and you should be OK.

Comment: A workaround for having to escape `|` in this case might be to use `--template '{short(node)}'` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Reimer! Also, works escaping '|' with '^' under Windows